# Video mixer api?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, audio, video

Can anybody suggest me some good Video mixer api for iphone/ipad to do basic functionalities like mixing audios in a video and saving them like it is  in this facebook app:
[https://apps.facebook.com/absolutremix/#*=*](https://apps.facebook.com/absolutremix/#_=_)

I would prefer not to use opengl.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that theres going to be API for some video and audio mixing. Apple demonstrates audio mixing using code here though.http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html